# Google App Engine with Python: Unable to update the data entity

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have read, read, and read again the documentation and do many search on the Web but I don't understand yet why my app doesn't work correctly.
When a user connects, he have to complete a form. The code for this works. When the user logs out, and then, logs in, the form fields are filled with his information. So, the data is correctly saved. But, when the user changes the form fields values and submits the form, data are not updated.

My model:

```
class Members(db.Model):
    account = db.UserProperty()
    hashtags = db.StringProperty()
```

Here the class to submit the form:

```
class Submit(webapp.RequestHandler):
def post(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()

    if user:
        url = users.create_logout_url('/')
        url_linktext = 'Logout'

        member = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Members WHERE account = :1", user)

        if member.count(1) > 0:
            m = Members(account=user)
            m.hashtags = ','.join([
                self.request.get('hashtag1'),
                self.request.get('hashtag2'),
                self.request.get('hashtag3')])
            m.put()
        else:
            member = Members()
            member.account = user
            member.hashtags = ','.join([
                self.request.get('hashtag1'),
                self.request.get('hashtag2'),
                self.request.get('hashtag3')])
            member.put()

        self.redirect('/')
    else:
        self.redirect('/')
```

Comment: basically whats happening is that you are not getting a member before you update it. you are using a gqlquery to see if there are existing members but then you create a new entity with `m = Member(account=user)` instead of using `m = member.get()`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are adding a new record instead of updating the existing record. For your code, the simplest fix would be to change this:

```
if member.count(1) > 0:
    m = Members(account=user)
```

to:

```
if member.count(1) > 0:
    m = member[0]
```

The reason your code is updating the existing record is because you have not assigned a key. To learn more about keys, you can read about them in [Kinds and Identifiers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Kinds_and_Identifiers).

Comment: or to make it more readable `member.get()` instead of a `member[0]`